# Vue.js 1.0.15 filtering lists cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Following a basic example of filtering lists (found here: https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vue-step-by-step/episodes/14 ), using the limitBy i got stuck on the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
```

here is my markup:

```
<div v-for="product in products | limitBy 2"> ... </div>
```

here is my products ajax call (products are pulling in just fine):

```
fetchProducts: function() {

        this.$http.get('api/internal/products', function(products) {

            this.$set('products', products);

        });

    }
```

My products get pulled in no problem but as soon as I try to add a filter I get this console error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should instantiate products as an empty array to start.  In your Vue component:

```
data:function(){
    return {
        products:[]
    }
}
```

This way it doesn't try to run the `limitBy` filter on an undefined variable while it's waiting for that ajax request.

Comment: AH! Thank you! This was giving me a lot of other issues, I had a hunch as to the cause but didn't know the fix. This works perfectly